# OpenGL otrhographic projection zoom and float precision

Tags: c++, opengl-es, precision, glm-math

I am working on a tile-based rendering application in GLES. It works like tile based maps (OSM etc.). As the user zooms in, smaller and smaller tiles are displayed. For projection, I setup a orthographic matrix (using glm library), that looks like this:

```
auto projMatrix = glm::ortho(-viewCenter_.x / scale_,
                             viewCenter_.x / scale_,
                             viewCenter_.y / scale_,
                             -viewCenter_.y / scale_,
                             -1.0f, 1.0f);
```

you can see the parameters are viewCenter (which doesn't change, it is half the screen resolution) and scale, which changes as user zooms in or out. All the numbers are of `float` type.

Than I multiply this projection with translation and model matrices to get the final MVP, passed to GLSL. The problem I am seeing is, when the scene is zoomed in a lot (scale_ > 200000), I can see the movement stops being smooth, the shapes start to slightly jitter.

Here is an example of a model matrix:

```
transform_ = glm::scale(glm::translate(glm::mat4(), { x * tileSize, y * tileSize, 0.f }), { tileSize, tileSize, 1.f });
```

I am guessing this is due to the floating point precision, buy I have no idea how to fix it. I think replacing the variables with double wouldn't help.

Comment: Have you tried changing the types to double yet?